# Threads in swing freezing - java

Tags: java, multithreading, swing, sleep, jtextpane

I'd like to realize a fake bash where when i append multiple strings on my output (JTextPane), there is a little wait between a message and another. I did it with a thread, but all freeze when I append a new message.
This is the code for append:

```
public void append(String s) {
    Thread t = new Thread(){
        public void run() {
            textPane.setText(textPane.getText()+"\n"+s);
            try {
                Thread.sleep((long) (Math.random()%1000));
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    };
    t.start();
    try {
        t.join();
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

But the result is that all freeze waiting all messages is written. What can I do?

Comment: You start a thread which sleeps, then you wait for that thread to end, which means that the `join()` call is no different than the `sleep()` call, i.e. the call doesn't return until the sleep timer has completed.

Comment: Don't use textPane.setText(textPane.getText() + "..."). This is not efficient as the getText() method needs to parse all the text in the text pane to create the output String. Then the setText() method need to reparse the String to find all the newlines in the String. Instead use `textPane.getDocument().insertString(...)`.

Comment: Also you may want to use a `SwingWorker`. It will create the Thread for you and make sure the text is added to the text pane on the Event Dispatch Thread (EDT). Read the section from the Swing tutorial on [Concurrency](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/index.html) for more information about the `EDT` and `SwingWorker`.